# How to prove $\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x)dx$ is equivilant with $\sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Omega} f_i(x)u_i(x)dx$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, optimization, convex-analysis, image-processing

I have a 2D image in $\Omega$ space. Assume that the space can be separated into $N$ sub-regions $\Omega_i$ such that $\Omega_i \cap\Omega_j=\emptyset$;  $\Omega_i \cup  \Omega_j=\Omega, \forall i,j=1... N$

Let $u_i(x)=1$ if $x \in \Omega_i$, otherwise $u_i(x)=0$. Then we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{N}f_i(x)u_i(x)=f_i(x)$ if $x \in \Omega_i$

I have a energy function that is defined as following
$$E_1(x)=\int_{\Omega} \sum_{i=1}^{N} f_i(x)dx$$

"Does the below equation $E_2(x)$ equate with above energy function $E_1(x)$?" How to prove it?
$$E_2(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{N} \int_{\Omega}  f_i(x)u_i(x)dx$$

Comment: $\Omega_i \cup \Omega_j=\emptyset$;  $\Omega_i \cap \Omega_j=\Omega, \forall i,j=1... N$  Is this correct?  The first part says each $\Omega_i$ is the empty set.  The second one says any two can be intersected to get the complete space?

Comment: Sorry. I mistaken between these condition. Let see my updated question.